# How can I manipulate Anomaly Warzone Earth savegames?

Tags: anomaly-warzone-earth

I'm experiencing a serious issue with AWE: the game is fun, it works well, then for some reason the game doesn't close cleanly *and I lose ALL progress I ever made in the game.*

When this happened after unlocking the 3rd mission, I didn't mind it *too* much, but this time I lost the entire first chapter, and my completion of Baghdad Mayhem. I'm not pleased at all, and I don't want to play through those missions again; I'd much rather resume the game from where I left it: the first mission of Tokyo.

Is there a way to unlock levels without playing them? Failing that, is there a savefile with all areas unlocked?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. I just started the game and I'm at level 1 again. Before, I was halfway Tokyo or something... Have you already found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @LarsVeldscholte I'm afraid I haven't. :(

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late for You but hope this will help somebody someday.

You must upload it in this location **{Steam}\userdata{ID}\91200\remote** like on [this Steam forum](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2035032).

This is [my save game](http://cl.ly/19121g2q2d15). All maps are accessible.